# Help with rails declarative_authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, declarative-authorization

I cant get this rule to be enforced at all... it allows anyone to get to this action.

Here's my rule

```
role :student do
    has_permission_on :relationships do 
      to :index
      if_attribute :student_id=> is {user.student.id}
    end
  end
```

Heres my controller action

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController

filter_resource_access :nested_in => :students

 def index
   @guardians = @student.guardians  
  end
```

I know I have it set up correctly cause this rule is working fine

```
has_permission_on :students do 
      to :show
      if_attribute :id => is {user.student.id}
    end
```

Where is the error in my rule definition?

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to test, but try this:

```
if_attribute :id=> is {user.student.id}
```